# Having trouble in Online Movie ticketing database design

Tags: sql-server-2008

@J2D8T i have done few changes in my code please tell if its correct also is it properly normalized? thanks in advance.

```
        use [fadi1]

    create table Customer (
    Cnic varchar (17) primary key not null,
    name varchar (30) not null,
    Cpassword varchar (30) not null,
    email varchar (40) ,
    contactno varchar (15) ,
    city varchar (30)
    );

    create table Adimn (
    Anic varchar (17) primary key not null,
    name varchar (30) not null,
    Cpassword varchar (30) not null, 
    email varchar (40) ,
    contactno varchar (15) ,
    city varchar (30)
    );

    create table Movie (
    M_id int primary key not null, 
    name varchar(25) not null,
    Mdescription varchar(500) not null,
    imagename varchar (100) not null,
    Actors varchar (100) not null,
    );

    create table Venue(
    V_id int primary key not null, 
    V_Name varchar(25) not null,
    Maxcapacity int not null,   
    );


    create table Shows (
    showid int primary key IDENTITY(1,1) not null, 
    V_id int not null, 
    M_id int not null ,  
    date_time datetime  not null unique,
    remaining_tickets int not null,
    foreign key (v_id) references Venue(v_id),
    foreign key (M_id) references Movie(M_id),

    );

    create table Tickets(
    showid int not null,
    Seat_no  int not null, -- (maxcap-remaining tickets)+1 from capacity table of given pk of that table 
    T_id int primary key IDENTITY(1,1) not null,  --(p.k)
    price int not null, 
    foreign key (showid) references Shows(showid) 
    );


    create table Booking (
    showid int not null,
    T_id int not null unique, 
    Cnic varchar(17)  not null, 
    booking_time datetime  not null,
    foreign key (showid) references Shows(showid),
    foreign key (T_id) references Tickets(T_id),
    foreign key (Cnic) references Customer(Cnic),
    constraint pk_IDBooking primary key(T_id,showid), 
    );
```

please inform me as soon as possible because i am not quite far from the deadline :D

Comment: Please describe exactly what you mean by `trouble`

Comment: how to link last three tables and reduce redundancy

Comment: what will be the primary keys of last three tables ? if a single user book five tickets how we will handle that?

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, there is no `password` data type in SQL Server. Since you have provided no details about how you're storing data, I converted it to varchar(50).

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a9b5)

```
create table Customer (
Cnic varchar (17) primary key not null,
name varchar (30) not null,
Cpassword varchar(50) not null,
email varchar (40) ,
contactno varchar (15) ,
city varchar (30) ,
)

create table Adimn (
Anic varchar (17) primary key not null,
name varchar (30) not null,
Cpassword varchar(50) not null,
email varchar (40) ,
contactno varchar (15) ,
city varchar (30) ,
)

create table Movie (
M_id int not null, 
name varchar(25) not null,
Mdescription varchar(500) not null,
imagename varchar (100) not null,
primary key (M_id)
);


create table Actors(
actor_id varchar(25) primary key not null ,
actor varchar(30)not null,
M_id int not null,
Act_role varchar (10)not null,
amountspent int ,
foreign key (M_id) REFERENCES Movie(M_id)
);

create table Venue(
V_id int primary key not null, 
M_id int not null,--F.k 
V_Name varchar(25)not null

);

create table Capacity(
M_id int not null, 
v_id int not null,
date_time varchar (15)  not null,
remaining_tickets int not null,
max_capacity int   not null, 
primary key (M_id, v_id ,date_time )

);


create table Booking (
v_id int not null, --key
T_id int not null,
M_id int not null,--key 
Cnic varchar(30) primary key not null,--(p.k))
date_time varchar (15) not null, -- (f.k ) 
);


create table Tickets(
Seat_no int primary key not null, -- (p.k))
T_id int not null,
M_id int not null, --(f.k)
price int not null,

);
```

Comment: Come on ([@TheOptimusPrimus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2517150/theoptimusprimus)) You can downvote more than this!

Answer (score 1):

I edited the answer to include only the code with some comments hope this solves your problem.

Edit from your original post:

```
create table Customer (
Cnic varchar (17) primary key not null,
name varchar (30) not null,
Cpassword password not null,
email varchar (40) ,
contactno varchar (15) ,
city varchar (30)
);

create table Adimn (
Anic varchar (17) primary key not null,
name varchar (30) not null,
Cpassword varchar (30) not null, // changed to varchar
email varchar (40) ,
contactno varchar (15) ,
city varchar (30)
);

create table Movie (
M_id int primary key not null, 
name varchar(25) not null,
Mdescription varchar(500) not null,
imagename varchar (100) not null
);

create table Actors(
actor_id varchar(25) primary key not null ,
actor varchar(30)not null,
M_id int not null,
Act_role varchar (10)not null,
amountspent int ,
foreign key (M_id) REFERENCES Movie(M_id)
);

create table Venue(
V_id int primary key not null, 
M_id int not null,--F.k 
V_Name varchar(25) not null,
foreign key (M_id) references Movie(M_id)
);

create table Capacity(
v_id int not null, // FK
M_id int not null unique, //FK 
date_time varchar (15)  not null unique,
remaining_tickets int not null,
max_capacity int   not null,
foreign key (v_id) references Venue(v_id),
foreign key (M_id) references Movie(M_id),
constraint pk_IDCapacity PRIMARY KEY (M_id,v_id,date_time) // this will create composite key
);

create table Tickets(
Seat_no int primary key not null, -- (p.k))
T_id int not null,
M_id int not null, --(f.k)
price int not null,
foreign key (M_id) references Capacity(M_id) 
);

create table Booking (
v_id int not null, //FK
T_id int not null, //FK
M_id int not null,//FK
Cnic varchar(30) primary key not null // Will this stil be neccessary
date_time varchar (15) not null, //FK
foreign key (v_id) references Venue(v_id),
foreign key (M_id) references Movie(M_id),
foreign key (date_time) references Capacity(date_time),
foreign key (T_id) references Tickets(T_id),
constraint pk_IDBooking primary key(v_id,M_id,T_id,date_time) //Can be in any order the PK's
);
```

Could probably be more compacted with normalization but it should work based on the code you have provided.

Comment: `you can't have 3 primary keys only one` Say what? You're completely wrong on this. First of all, it's a `composite key` and completely legal. By slapping UNIQUE on the 3 columns in Capacity changes the semantics. They want uniqueness across all of those columns, not restricted to per column. You can of course make those 3 columns unique *and* define a primary key on a separate set of columns but that would just be silly in this case

Comment: if a Customer have to book for two tickets for two different movies then how we will save the entry in booking table as Cnic is the primary key at it should not be repeated?

Comment: @billinkc yes true but creating a composite key they should rather use `CONSTRAINT pk_ID PRIMARY KEY (M_id,v_id,date_time)` then instead of `primary key(m_id,v_id,date_time)` that could give you errors.

Comment: @user3047690 I will edit the post so you can test if it solves your problem.

Comment: @user3047690 sorry for taking so long it needed to finish something

Comment: yes i am also working on it thanks for working on it let me know when you are done.

Comment: @J2D8T i am getting an error at the last line  constraint pk_ID primary key(v_id,M_id,T_id,date_time) "cannot add multiple primary key cconstraints"

Comment: I have made edits to table Capacity and table Booking in my answer.